# I have a list with values = ["a","b","c","d"]

Tags: python, list

I have a list with `values = ["a","b","c","d"]`

I am expecting output in below 2 formats. Could any one please help.
I have tried using for x in list, range but no luck.

**Output 1:**

```
a
b
c
d 

a
b
c
d
```

**output 2:**

```
a
a
a
a

b
b
b
b

c
c
c
c

d
d
d
d
```

Comment: What have you tried and what output did you get?

Answer (score 1):

for the first output, something simple like this will do the trick:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for x in range(2):
    for y in a:
        print(x)
```

As for the second, I am not sure if the four times is static or comes from the number of elements in the array, if it is the first:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for x in a:
    for y in range(4):
        print(x)
```

If it is the second:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for x in a:
    for y in range(len(a)):
        print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

In the first output, you are printing the whole list two times. And in the *output 2* you are trying to print every element four times.

For the first output, you can use something like this

```
>>> print(*values*2, sep='\n')
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
```

The `values*2` part repeats the list twice. The `*` ahead of `values*2` unpacks the list. The `sep='\n'` argument, makes sure every element is printed on the next line.

For output two you can do the following

```
>>> _ = [print(i) for i in values for k in range(4)]
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
c
d
d
d
d
```